# Specify custom format for DecimalFormat Class

Tags: java

I am trying to represent an integer in 12 digit format, 10 digit format etc with leading zereos. I have used this:-

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("000000000000");
String invoiceAmountString = decimalFormat.format(IntegerValue);
```

I want a generic function such that when i pass 10 or any other value it should use that number of zereos in DecimalFormat. I have an idea like this;-

```
case 10:
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0000000000"); // 10 digit
case 12:
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("000000000000"); // 12 digit
```

but decimal format can go from 5-25 digit. I need a function like:-

```
convertToFormat(Integer amount, Integer noOfDigits)
```

such that if i pass 5,10,15 or whatever value in `noOfDigits` it should use that number of zereos in DecimalFormat.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can build the zeros pattern with a loop using `StringBuilder`.

Comment: RTFM http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
String s = String.format("%0" + numberOfDigits + "d", amount);
```